# Mysql transaction not working in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, transactions

I wrote a stored procedure and I put at the beginning these statements :

```
SET autocommit = 0;

START TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
```

I finish with `COMMIT;` statement.

but transaction is not working.

Can you help?

**update 1:**

Could this instruction

```
 SET @now = unix_timestamp () * 1000;
```

cause an implicit commit?

**update 2 :** my code is like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stored_proc()

SQL SECURITY DEFINER

BEGIN

SET autocommit = 0;

START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM `TABLE1` WHERE `COLUMN1` = value;

INSERT INTO TABLE1...

SET @now = unix_timestamp() * 1000;

DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN2 = value;

INSERT INTO `TABLE2` ...;

COMMIT;

END
```

I have an ihm which displays data of table TABLE2. I notice that when the stored procedure runs, the IHM displays null values. This means that the commit was made after the second DELETE and before the INSERT

**Update 3**

`select @@tx_isolation;` gives me `REPEATABLE-READ` and `show create table table2`gives me `engine = InnoDB` at the end of result

Comment: Are you using InnoDB? MyISAM doesn't implement transactions.

Comment: Yes I'm using innodb.

Comment: What happens instead when you say it is "not working", how do you know it's not working? Your code in the update doesn't cause an implicit commit, e.g. any ddl code (like `alter table`) would do that. You should add your whole procedure (you can abbreviate, the exact code is not relevant, e.g. just write `select ...`) and describe what (doesn't) happen and what you expect. And btw, you don't need to use `set autocommit = 0` to start a transaction, `start transaction` is used to start a transaction. A `commit` will not reset `autocommit` to 1, so you would need a `commit` from now on.

Comment: Anyone can help ?

Comment: Thanks for the update, now its a lot clearer what you are asking. This behaviour should happen if you either use a MyISAM-table (which doesn't support transactions) or if your isolation level is set too low. Try: `show create table table2` and at the end of the output look for something like `engine = MyISAM` or `engine = InnoDB`. To see your isolation level, use `select @@tx_isolation;`

Comment: I've updated post with results

Comment: The problem was that In my java code, I had `<Resource username="$user" url="$url" 
                 type="javax.sql.DataSource" password="$pwd" name="$jndi" maxWait="-1" maxIdle="$idle" 
                 maxActive="$max" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" defaultTransactionIsolation="READ-UNCOMMITTED" />` I updated it with `defaultTransactionIsolation="REPEATABLE_READ"` Thanks very much @Solarflare for your help. I hadn't thought about isolation level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that In my java code, I had

```
<Resource username="$user" url="$url" type="javax.sql.DataSource" password="$pwd" name="$jndi" maxWait="-1" maxIdle="$idle" maxActive="$max" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" defaultTransactionIsolation="READ-UNCOMMITTED" />
```

I updated with defaultTransactionIsolation="REPEATABLE_READ" Thanks very much @Solarflare for your help. I hadn't thought about isolation level.